# Bee Sharps sponsored by Albert Fink

Tags: bioshock-infinite

This is a question about the Bee Sharps, a barbershop quartet group we come across very early in the game.

[image]

Spoilers in question below:

> The first time we see them, they are singing the [God Only Knows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Only_Knows) a song released by the Beach Boys in 1966, some 50 years before the events in the game took place. The sign in the picture (partially obscured) says, "The music of tomorrow today!". Since the group is sponsored by the industrialist Jeremiah Fink brother Albert Fink, does that mean at some point he (or both of them) had access to the time rifts in the game? If not, who brought this piece of culture back to 1912?

Comment: Heh, the Bee Sharps?  I wonder if the creators watched [The Simpsons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2eDoeIh64o) when they were younger :P

Comment: "What is the most admirable creature on God’s green earth? Why, it’s the bee! Have you ever seen a bee on vacation? Have you ever seen a bee take a sick day? Well, my friend, the answer is no! So I say, be….the bee! Be the bee!"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spoilers ahead, don't read until much later in the game, same deal as all the rest of the Bioshock Infinite questions.

Later on in the game, in a sort of side-exploration destination,

> you will find a tear in the house of Albert Fink, as you head back to Comstock house after finding the third tear. From it, you will hear a modern song ("Girls Just Want to have Fun", of all things). Jerimiah Fink congratulates his brother for discovering such rifts in a Voxophone, saying "Dear brother, these holes in the thin air continue to pay dividends. I know not which musician you borrow your notes from, but if he has half the genius of the biologist I now observe, well...then you are to be the Mozart of Columbia." This implies that both of them had access to the tears.

**Update**

After digging through the Voxophone transcripts, I've found even more answers on the significance of this.

A voxophone found in Finkton Proper or in the Good Time Club recorded by Jeremiah Fink:

> "I had thought you a fool, dear brother. When you told me that you heard wonderful music trumpetting from holes in the thin air. I began to doubt your mental integrity. But not only have you made your fortune from these doodads, you have lit the path for me as well."

That voxophone doesn't have much significance until later, in the factory:

> "These holes have shown me yet another wonder, though I've yet to see the application for it. They illuminate a merger of machine and man that is somehow the lesser, yet the greater, of both parties. The process seems to be irreversible. Perhaps, though, Comstock will have some need of this kind of thing to keep watch in that tower of his."

This likely reveals the origin of

> the Handymen, Firemen, and possibly the Motorized Patriots.

The final voxophone loses significance, given these others:

> "Dear brother, these holes in the thin air continue to pay dividends. I know not which musician you borrow your notes from, but if he has half the genius of the biologist I now observe, well...then you are to be the Mozart of Columbia."

The real significance of the room...

> ...lies in the actual tear in the room, since before this point, it's not entirely clear what exactly Fink means by "holes in the thin air"

Comment: Thanks that clears it up. I tried to find the voxophone text on wikia, but that site's a mess. I think the answer would be more complete if you could post the text that backs up what you're saying here.

Comment: I'll look for it, either in-game or online, and post it as soon as I find it. There are also apparently more answers on how Jeremiah uses them as well...

Comment: *"This likely reveals the origin of.."* - the songbird as well, given the reference to Comstock's tower.

Comment: True, true. There are a number of things Fink probably got from Rapture. This game, man... The fact that I'm still thinking about it a week later speaks volumes.